# jQuery .not(element) doesn't work in mobile browser (Firefox, Chorme, Safari)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

I would like customize `input` elements except input element with id `#search`, so i used `not('#search')`, but this doesn't work in mobile browser (safari with iphone 9.2 and with app Firefox and Chrome). In desktop browser works very well. What i tried:

```
    $('input').not('#search').css({ 
        'max-width': '90%',
        'border-radius': '8px',
        'color': '#000'
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jfxpehrL/2/

So in mobile browser not() doesn't work and input `#search` is customized

How is possible ?

I have other way to do what i want to do ?

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english :)

Comment: I thought it was clear ... I also wrote in the title: not(id) ... so also the input #search has css of jquery code

Comment: In that case, why doesn't it work? because that's not anything special that shouldn't work in mobile. I think you are mis-dianosing the problem.

Comment: you are not costructive..do you want screenshot of mobile browser ??? mha....

Comment: No, but you could explain what lead you to believe the problem is with .not and not .css or something else.

Comment: That code should work. Check if you have errors on developer console.

Comment: and... your fiddle works just fine for me in chrome mobile.

Comment: @KevinB i have that code only in one page of my website. And doesn't work only with mobile browser. If i delete that code (where customize input element),  #search dont'have css. If i change that code and delete "not(#id)" change nothing! So not() doesn't work...

Comment: Are you sure the target element actually has the id you expect it to in mobile? What would make it not have that id in mobile? (hint: none of the code you provided would cause this problem)

Comment: yes the id element doesn't change :/

Comment: that isn't possible fortunately. .not() works just fine on mobile, therefore the only possible reason for this to not be working as expected is for that '#search' selector to not be finding any elements to exclude (which guarantees that the element doesn't have the id.) we're going in circles at this point, so.... maybe we should try something else. What does `$("input#search").length` give you in mobile vs the browser, at that exact spot in the code? output it into the console, or if you cant view the console in mobile, put it into a div somewhere.

Comment: I solved it by adding $('#search').attr('style',''); infact now i don't have problems.. but in this way i don't understand the problem. What you suggest is ok but i'm not a good programmer and i don't know use console.. however thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

You can also try `:not()` selector:

```
$('input:not(#search)').css({ 
    'max-width': '90%',
    'border-radius': '8px',
    'color': '#000'
});
```